# use a variable value in lookup mongoose expression

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, lookup

I am using a mongoose model that brings documents and I add an aggregate to "join" with other collection. The real problem is when I use aggregate I cannot filter documents in the "original" collection (similar to findOne()). So when I use the aggregate function I get all documents but I just need 1.

i.e. (this is only an example for a point describe)

```js
Collection A = {id,name,birthdate,dni} 
   Collection B = {avatar,dni.....} 
   a.aggregate([ '$lookup': {
       'from': 'avatars',
       'localField': 'dni',
       'foreignField': 'dni',
       'as': 'aditionalinfo' 
   } ])
```

this result in a full collection A + additionalinfo object from B for each document but supposed to bring one person from collection A with the additional data (additionalinfo). I mean, I need to bring one document "joined" with the corresponding document from the other collection.

here is the last code I tried

```js
let ley = await leyes.aggregate([
{         
 '$lookup': {           
   'from': 'digessituacion',           
   'localField': 'idsituacio',           
   'foreignField': 'idsituacio',            
   'as': 'situacion'        
 }       
}, {
   '$lookup': { 
      'from': 'digescategoria',            
      'localField': 'catego',            
      'foreignField': 'catego',            
      'as': 'categoria'         
    }
   }, 
{         
  '$match': { 
     'ley': 8996 // this is the number which I need to set variable cause is passed from params         
  }
}]);
```

this is the schema

```js
    import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
    const leyesSchema = new Schema(
      {
        ley: Number,
        resumen: String,
        notas: String,
        txtley: String,
        catego: String,
        detcatego: String,
        idsituacio: Number,
        promulgada: Date,
        sancionada: Date,
       
      },
      { timestamps: false, versionKey: false }
    );
    export default model("leyes", leyesSchema);
```

and the Schema of collection needed to "join"

```js
    import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
    const digessituacionSchema = new Schema(
      {
        idsituacio: Number,
        situacion: String,
      },
      { timestamps: false, versionKey: false }
    );
    export default model("digessituacion", digessituacionSchema);
```

if I put the number manually works but is not usable cause it must be a variable. Anyone knows the way for do this? It is possible?

Comment: Can you add your schema models to the question?

Comment: @NeNaD I updated post with schemas

Comment: Your code should work. Do you maybe have multiple documents with `ley` equal to `8996` in your database? Also, one recommendation: you should always put `$match` stage to be the first one, so it can leverage indexes.

Comment: No. The problem is that number 8996 must be a variable number given trough req.params.... if i put number manually works. The question is about using a variable in the $match operator

Comment: I added an answer, can you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `req.params` is parsed, they are always parsed as type `string`. Since your `ley` field is of type `number`, you have to parse it first:

```js
"$match": { 
  "ley": parseInt(req.params.ley, 10)     
}
```

Comment: i am getting error "parseISO is not defined". But i changed to parseInt and it works great!. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey, sorry... It should be `parseInt`. I updated my answer. Can you try it again?

Comment: I did that change. Works great. Thanks again for your time